# How to access to a static cell

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

I created a TableView directly in the storyboard; this tableView contains 8 static cells (style basic) in 4 section; now, how could I edit via code these cells? for example for to change textLabel, backgroundColor, separator ecc
I tried to set an identifier to each cel but didn't work...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For static cells created in the storyboard, you can simply set the `IBOutlet` for the elements you want to edit by ctrl-dragging from the storyboard to the corresponding view controller, to end up with something like this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var cell1: UITableViewCell!
  @IBOutlet weak var cell2: UITableViewCell!
}
```

Then you can access the built-in elements in the Basic view with `cell1.textLabel` etc.

Check out [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingOutlet.html) about setting `IBOutlets`.

To change the background color, you can do it in the storyboard UI directly or access the `backgroundColor` property. You might want to read the [UITableViewCell Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html).

Comment: thanks a lot! but I don't have any elements in my cells, because they are basic style and in any case how could i change background color of each cell? do not exist anything like var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView. for to access to the tableView cells?

Comment: There is a property on UITableViewCell called backgroundColor. So, you could do `nameOfYourCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()`

Comment: @FabioCelli - You have two basic approaches: Either create outlets to the appropriate controls in your static table view cells, like p4sh4 suggested, or don't use static cells at all and instead use cell prototypes, but then implement the standard `UITableViewDataSource` methods. If you're changing all of the properties of the cells including labels, images, cell background colors, etc., your cells don't sound very "static" to me. Regardless, I think you should accept p4sh4's answer: You might not like the answer, but it is correct.

Comment: @Rob In this application I'm going to make, I'm using prototypes cell for example to populate a table view with data by arrays  or dataManager, and in this case this is a menu table list (label and image are chosen a priori) and I imagined the these cells might be static cells.
however I'm sorry if this question would have seemed stupid: I know outlets and I looked for other information on the forum, but I honestly thought there was another solution to the problem!
however thanks a lot to all you, p4sh4, Rob and Epic Defeater, you were fast and available ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Thanks p4sh4 for @IBOutlet suggestion.
But instead of multiple Outlets, you should try an "Outlet Collection".

```
 @IBOutlet var tableLabelCollection: [UILabel]!

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("accessory Button Tapped: \(indexPath.row) => \(tableLabelCollection[indexPath.row].text)")
    }
```