# Passing data from a static tableViewCell to another viewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a tableView with static cells.

What I wan't, is that when the user selects a certain cell, the text from this cell, is passed to the previous viewController. I have never worked with static cells before and I can only seem to find tutorials and other questions regarding activating the cells, so they leed to another viewController.

So how do I pass data (what's written in the cell), when the cell is selected?

Is it a code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Do I use segues? Then there will have to be hundreds of segues, if I have hundreds of cell, that the user can choose, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you are assigning Array of String to DiaryQuestionLabel.text which accepts string only in destinationViewController. Just change the type of chosenQuestion to String in destinationViewController as below.

```
@IBOutlet weak var DiaryQuestionLabel: UILabel!
var chosenQuestion: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   DiaryQuestionLabel.text = chosenQuestion
}
```

In your tableViewController You need to pass the value of selected index from your datasource array which you have used to set the data in your tableviewcell.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     if segue.destination is UpdatingIdentifiers {
     let vc = segue.destination as? UpdatingIdentifiers
     let selectedRowIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
     // Get tableviewcell object from indexpath and assign it's value to chosenQuestion of another controller.  
     let cell = yourtableview.cellForRow(at: selectedRowIndex)
     let label = cell.viewWithTag(420) as! UILabel
     vc?.chosenQuestion = label.text
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems logic enough. Only I don't know what to write, where you wrote "dataSourceArray". I'm not sure my dataSourceArray has a name? I used following code to implement the values in the cells:  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PotentielQuestion", for: indexPath)         So does it have a name or should I give it a name somehow?

Comment: @AntonBjerg What you are displaying in your cell? 

If you only want to display selected index in DiaryQuestionLabel then you just need to pass vc?.chosenQuestion = String(selectedRowIndex.row).

Comment: I'm just displaying a few lines of pure String - and that is all I need to pass to DiaryQuestionLabel. But when I use your code there, it gives me the error: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(Int?)' .  Maybe it considers the value an Int because of the lines, that goes: if indexPath.row == 0 { and so on... But when I type Int(selectedRowIndex.row), it gives me the opposite error.....

Comment: Are you displaying static text in your cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath OR using array of string to display it in cell?

Comment: Static text! It's just a list of "potentiel questions", where when the user taps one of these given questions, that question, should go to a label in another viewcontroller. There are no adding extra cells or anything. Just plain static text. 
I'm sorry if describing my issues vague! Appreciate your help!

Comment: @AntonBjerg If you are using static text in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method then you need to get tableviewcell object from indexpath and assign it's value to chosenQuestion of another controller.  

     let cell = yourtableview.cellForRow(at: selectedRowIndex)
     vc?.chosenQuestion = cell.textLabel?.text

Comment: I'm very sorry. I'm sure it's me who's an idiot. But I don't understand where you wan't me to put these two lines of code.

Comment: You are referring to comments. I just updated my answer in override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) method. Can you please check it.

Comment: Well, I guess a little progress with the updated answer! Now I can run the app - and it doesn't crash untill the moment, when I select a certain cell - then it gives me the: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optionan value on the line: vc?.chosenQuestion = (cell?.textLabel?.text)! My guess is that it has something to do with the fact, that I don't understand what "textLabel" refers to? I don't think I have anything by this name? :o

Comment: I assumed you are setting static text value in your cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath method like this. cell.textLabel.text = "Static text". If not, then you have to do it.

How you are setting static text to your cell?

Comment: I am more or less. I write in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method underneeth the dequeueReusableCell line: let label = cell.viewWithTag(420) as! UILabel
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            label.text = "If you had one wish, what would it be?"      But when I just write "label" instead of textlabel as in your example, it tells me, it does not have a member called "label"...?

Comment: @AntonBjerg Again updated my answer based on your comment. Please check it.

Comment: Wauw!! It works.... halfway! It finally works so that the text is now transferred to the other viewController's label - thanks! That's really nice! The only problem is, that this whole issue was supposed to be written in to two different tableViewControllers. So that in this tableViewController you choose a question, which will be passed into the normal viewController. Then you click onto tableViewController2 and choose an " extra identifier", which is then passed back to normal viewController's other label. --> --> -->

Comment: Problem now is that the "updating lines", the  DiaryQuestionLabel.text = chosenQuestion
        RandomIdentifierLabel.text = chosenIdentifier are both inside ViewDidLoad.... This means that when you go to the tableView with questions and choose one, it's blanks the "identifiers", when you come back - and the other way around. I guess this is, as I said, because the "Updating the label - lines" are inside viewDidLoad, so everytime the view is loaded, they are used. But where in god's name else to put them? I seems stupid for the user to put them inside an "activate-button".... Damnit!

Answer (score 0):

Text label is of type String. You are assigning an array of string to it.
Also the same mistake you are doing with assigning indexPath to an array of Strings. 
You are messing around with types.

Change to this:

```
vc?.chosenQuestion = tableView.cellForRow(at: selectedRowIndex).textLabel?.text
```

Change your variable to

```
var chosenQuestion = ""
```

And in viewDidLoad()

```
DiaryQuestionLabel.text = chosenQuestion
```

Comment: I know I'm messing around with the types. What I don't know, is which types to use for it to work correctly... It seems I should just work with strings like this: 
var chosenQuestion:String = "" & DiaryQuestionLabel.text = chosenQuestion, but then I still get the error: Cannot assign value of type 'IndexPath?' to type 'String' in the tableViewController. That's why I'm trying to make it into an array in the beleive, that this might help?

Comment: Thanks! Only this there I don't get, is that you assign "yourLabel" in the tableViewController? In there I don't have any labels except for the one attached to the cell, which doesn't have a name. So what do you mean by the last piece of that code 'yourLabel.text? :)

Comment: In this case, make it `textLabel?.text`

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to assign the wrong type to your variables. That is the cause of your errors.
For example,
You have defined `chosenQuestion` as an array of String values, i.e. `[String]`, but you are attempting to assign an IndexPath at the following statement, `vc?.chosenQuestion = selectedRowIndex`.

To fix your problem,
You need to extract the specific string from your data source by utilising the `IndexPath` that you have stored into the `selectedRowIndex` variable.

For example, 
If your data source array is called, `myArray`, you can do the following:

```
var selectedRowIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
vc?.chosenQuestion = myArray[selectedRowIndex]
```

and then change your variable,
`var chosenQuestion = ""`

Finally, inside `viewDidLoad()`:
`DiaryQuestionLabel.text = chosenQuestion`

Comment: Thank! That makes a lot of sense! Only I don't have a name for my data source array - I'm just using the function:   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PotentielQuestion", for: indexPath   So I don't know how to refer to this data source array?

Comment: You're welcome. May I know how you are populating your table view? That would help clarify things.

Comment: override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PotentielQuestion", for: indexPath)
        
        let label = cell.viewWithTag(420) as! UILabel
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            label.text = "If you had one wish, what would it be?"

Comment: It looks like a mess when writing a code in a commentfield... But I'm using the dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:XXX) - function. And then just filling in text in each cell manually, by saying, "If indexpath = 0, print: "bla bla bla" . Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple way. This is similar to [Ali_Habeeb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52716713) with more details.

In your `didSelectRowAt`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let question = yourDataArray[indexPath.row]
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil)
    let newVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newVCIdentifier") as! NewViewController
    newVC.choosenQuestion = question
    self.show(newVC, sender: self)
}
```

In your newVC:

```
class NewViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var DiaryQuestionLabel: UILabel!

  var choosenQuestion = ""

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     DiaryQuestionLabel.text = choosenQuestion
  }
}
```

This is a very simple format, and should not produce any error and if does, then check your dataArray.

Comment: I think the reason why this is not working, is that I didn't mention in my question, that I'm only displaying static text in the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath. So I don't have any so called "data source array", as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Are you using static cells? only in that case static text is possible.

Comment: I am now. But the tableView was working fine independently without static cells before though. But now that I am, I still get the same errors when trying to pass the data, when selected.

Comment: First update your question with full information, by your this question form, everyone will take it as dynamic cells and think that you are using a dataArray or dataModel for displaying text in it.

Comment: And for static cells, look here may be you can get any help.    [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737114/how-to-access-to-a-static-cell]

Comment: I updated my question now. Maybe it is clearer for you to see, where i mess it up now? Because I still can't get the prepare for segue to work?